# Apache Drill Authentication in Windows

Tags: apache-drill

I am new in Apache Drill.I am running drill in embedded mode with window 10 operating system.

My question is how to authenticate drill. I want if any one start drill, it will ask for user name and password to start drill.

I know that drill use PAM Authentication. But I don't know how to use PAM in window 8.1 operating system & where and how to store username & password.

Please Suggest me or if possible give me some example how to restrict user to access drill in window 8.1 operating system.

> Is Windows security supported, and if not: what would be the recommended route for adding Windows security?

Comment: @adeneche  :- Is there any solution..?

Comment: @dev ツ:- Is There any solution..?

Comment: I have not worked upon authentication in drill

Comment: I don't have much experience with drill authentication either

Comment: @adeneche:- Ok No problem.. Thanks for replying..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use custom authentication and configure in override.conf example class is specified in documentation 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-user-authentication/

If you are trying to give access to few folders on your machine. Remove dfs.root from storage plugin and give access to the folders you would like to share.

Comment: :- I have gone through this document. But didn't able to authenticate my drill in window operating  system. If Possible Please share some example for authentication in `WINDOW 8.1` Operating System.

Comment: I have change my drill-override.conf file :- `drill.exec: { cluster-id: "drillbits1",zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  sys.store.provider.local.path="/E:/Apache Drill 1.6/apache-drill-1.6.0/Storage Plugins", http: { enabled: true, ssl_enabled: true, port: 8047 session_max_idle_secs: 3600 # Default value 1hr },  impersonation {enabled: true, max_chained_user_hops: 3  }, security.user.auth {enabled: true, packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security", impl: "pam",  pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]  },}` While giving this files  i am not able to start my drill.Now How to start my drill.

Comment: :- Hi... I am trying to create custom authenticator in window with the help of drill link:-https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-user-authentication/ , I want to know what are the classes and jar files required for compiling the java file.